# Ionic native iBeacon plugin throws Cannot read property 'locationManager' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, webpack, ionic-native

I'm trying to integrate [iBeacon](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/ibeacon) plugin into my Ionic 5 App but it doesn't work at all.

When I try to call

```
this.delegate = this.ibeacon.Delegate();
```

then on the device, I obtain the following error all the time.

```
vendor-es2015.js:40772 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'locationManager' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'locationManager' of undefined
```

it is connected with the following code in the plugin:

```
var delegate = new _ionic_native_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__["cordova"].plugins.locationManager.Delegate();
```

I've added  IBeaconprovider into the main module and also I'm using imports from '@ionic-native/ibeacon/ngx'

My package versions:

```
"@ionic/core":  "5.1.0"
"@ionic-native/core": "5.25.0"
"@ionic-native/ibeacon": "5.25.0"
"@angular/common": "8.2.14"
```

I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or there is a bug in the plugin.

[Link](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-5-angular-8-ibeacon-native-plugin-doesnt-work/188980) to the original question on Ionic Forum

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3):

For anyone how is still facing the same issue. This is the solution:

1. Install the plugins,

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ibeacon
npm install @ionic-native/ibeacon
```

2. Modify the following three files in path `node_modules/@ionic-native/ibeacon` with the ones in the repository [ionic5ibeacon](https://github.com/YouQam/ionic5ibeacon)

- index.js
- ngx/index.js
- ivy_ngcc/ngx/index.js

The solution has been tested using both iOS and Android devices. [see](https://github.com/YouQam/Bluetooth-Beacons-Scanner)

Thanks [IT-Dan](https://github.com/IT-Dan)

Answer (score 1):

What I did to workaround this was:
1.- Removed the current android platform (ionic cordova platform rm android)
2.- Installed another cordova android version (ionic cordova paltform add android@^8.1.0-nightly.2019.9.10.42c0cba7)
3.- Rebuilded project (ionic cordova build android)
4.- Run the project

Hope this works for you too

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because the Android version is different in Cordova. You should change it.

The current version is `android@^8.1.0-nightly.2019.9.10.42c0cba7`.

And the Ionic command to change it is:

```sh
ionic cordova platform add android@^8.1.0-nightly.2019.9.10.42c0cba7
```