# Ionic native Ibeacon ReferenceError: device is not defined

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ibeacon, ionic-native, beacon

### TLDR: Ibeacon module example does not work

I have a small app in Ionic 5 using capacitor.

I want to use [the Ibeacon library](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/ibeacon), but I get the error :

[image: The error caused by the code]

Ressource for the library is scarse and I have only found people having issue when the delegate is undefined causing the LocatonManager error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61662058/ionic-native-ibeacon-plugin-throws-cannot-read-property-locationmanager-of-und).

I also tried to look what is causing the error, apparently the device mentioned is part of the [device library](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/device). So I check if the Ibeacon library properly import the device one and it does in `node_modules\cordova-plugin-ibeacon\plugin.xml`, like so :

```xml
   <!-- Version is set to anything because the only feature we use is the device.platform property which was available
    since forever. The added benefit is that we don't force the consumers of this plugin to use a certain version of
    the device plugin. -->
    <dependency id="cordova-plugin-device" version="*" />
```

My class is pretty much the example given in the Ibeacon page:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { IBeacon } from '@ionic-native/ibeacon/ngx';
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-beacon',
  templateUrl: './beacon.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./beacon.page.scss'],
})
export class BeaconPage implements OnInit {
  public beacons: any[] = [];

  constructor(
    private ibeacon: IBeacon,
    private platform: Platform,
    private _utils: UtilsService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('ngOnInit');

    if (!this.platform.is('android')) {
      console.log('Beacon related activity only available on Android');
      return;
    }

    // create a new delegate and register it with the native layer
    let delegate = this.ibeacon.Delegate();
    console.log('delegate :', delegate);

    // Subscribe to some of the delegate's event handlers
    delegate.didRangeBeaconsInRegion().subscribe(
      (data) => console.log('didRangeBeaconsInRegion: ', data),
      (error) => console.error()
    );
    delegate.didStartMonitoringForRegion().subscribe(
      (data) => console.log('didStartMonitoringForRegion: ', data),
      (error) => console.error()
    );
    delegate.didEnterRegion().subscribe((data) => {
      console.log('didEnterRegion: ', data);
    });

    let beaconRegion = this.ibeacon.BeaconRegion(
      'deskBeacon',
      'F7826DA6-ASDF-ASDF-8024-BC5B71E0893E'
    );

    this.ibeacon.startMonitoringForRegion(beaconRegion).then(
      () => console.log('Native layer received the request to monitoring'),
      (error) =>
        console.error('Native layer failed to begin monitoring: ', error)
    );
  }
}
```

Also I imported the IBeacon module inside my module.ts like so :

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { BeaconPageRoutingModule } from './beacon-routing.module';

import { BeaconPage } from './beacon.page';
import { IBeacon } from '@ionic-native/ibeacon/ngx';

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule, IonicModule, BeaconPageRoutingModule],
  declarations: [BeaconPage],
  providers: [IBeacon],
})
export class BeaconPageModule {}
```

Did I forget to do something ? Why is device undefined ? Should I also import the device library ?

I should mention I have the device library installed.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the lib they use the `device` to check the `plataform`, that is the code:

```
BeaconRegion.isValidUuid = function (uuid) {

    // https://github.com/petermetz/cordova-plugin-ibeacon/issues/328
    // If we are on Android, then allow the UUID to be specified as a wild-card (omitted)
    var isAndroid = device && device.platform === "Android";
    if (uuid === BeaconRegion.WILDCARD_UUID && isAndroid) {
        return true;
    }

    var uuidValidatorRegex = this.getUuidValidatorRegex();
    return uuid.match(uuidValidatorRegex) != null;
};
```

You can check right here https://github.com/petermetz/cordova-plugin-ibeacon/blob/270ffbbc12159861a16e5e81481103c1e09139cb/www/model/BeaconRegion.js#L38

So, you have to install the following plugin-in https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/device

```
npm install cordova-plugin-device
npm install @ionic-native/device
ionic cap sync
```

Then the find this `device` reference and the problem will be solved.

Comment: I already had installed Device. I forgot to mention it in my post I am adding it.